# How to kill process by non-admin account?

Tags: windows-server-2008

OS: Windows 2008 R2

I have an application that needs stopping for backup. 
How to grant a user to kill process without administrator privileges?
User must be able to kill process from other users. 
Or another idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is almost impossible using native Windows tools. I've built a product called **System Frontier** that let's you delegate rights to kill processes, manage services and much more. It's very easy to setup and all access is role based. Check it out [here](http://systemfrontier.com).

Comment: Please read our [faq] in particular [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://serverfault.com/faq#promotion). Our community is very sensitive to overt self  promotion and you're running close to the line.

Comment: I've tried to post only where I feel like this product would be a possible solution when no native alternative exists. But, point taken.